# Property files in Internationalization in Struts 2

Tags: struts2, internationalization

I want to know while developing an internationalization application in struts2 where to put property files named "global" as base name and "Action" as Base name using eclipse?

How are properties file loaded in struts2(since we are using any statement for property loading).How does control flow?

What are reasons if I am getting error like request resource not available on running application?

**index.jsp:**

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
        pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <%@taglib uri="/struts-tags" prefix="s" %>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Internationalization</title>
    </head>
    <body>
     <h1><s:text name="global.heading"/></h1>
    <s:url id="indexEn" action="locale" namespace="/">
     <s:param name="request_locale">en</s:param>
    </s:url>
    <s:url id="indexUR" action="locale" namespace="/">
     <s:param name="request_locale">ur</s:param>
    </s:url>
    <s:url id="indexHN" action="locale" namespace="/">
    <s:param name="request_locale">hn</s:param>
    </s:url>

    <s:a href="%{indexEn}">English</s:a>
    <s:a href="%{indexUR}">Urdu</s:a>
    <s:a href="%{indexHN}">Hindi</s:a>

     <s:form action="emp">
     <s:textfield name="name" key="global.name" size="20"/>
     <s:textfield name="age" key="global.age" size="20"/>
     <s:submit name="submit" key="global.submit" align="right"/>

     </s:form> 
    </body>
    </html>
```

**action file:**

```
    package com.Localization.myPack;
    import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;
    public class Employee extends ActionSupport{
    private String name;
    private int age;
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }
    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
    public String execute()
    {
     return"success";   
    }
    }
Locale file:
global.heading=Select locale
global.age=Age
global.submit=submit
global.success=Successfully authenticated
```

**struts.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
   "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
   "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">
   <struts>
   <constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />
<!--    <constant name="struts.custom.i18n.resources" value="global" /> -->

   <package name="default"  extends="struts-default">
   <action name="emp" class="com.Localization.myPack.Employee" method="execute">
    <result name="success">/success.jsp</result>
   <result name="input">/index.jsp</result>
   </action>

   <action name="locale" class="com.Localization.myPack.Locale" method="execute">
  <result name="success">/index.jsp</result>
   </action>

  </package>
   </struts>
```

***Stack trace:***

```
May 04, 2016 1:47:28 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:Localization' did not find a matching property.
May 04, 2016 1:47:28 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server version:        Apache Tomcat/7.0.57
May 04, 2016 1:47:28 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server built:          Nov 3 2014 08:39:16 UTC
May 04, 2016 1:47:29 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server number:         7.0.57.0
May 04, 2016 1:47:29 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Name:               Windows 7
May 04, 2016 1:47:29 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Version:            6.1
May 04, 2016 1:47:29 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Architecture:          x86
May 04, 2016 1:47:29 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JAVA_HOME:             C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_20\jre
May 04, 2016 1:47:29 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Version:           1.8.0_20-b26
May 04, 2016 1:47:29 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
May 04, 2016 1:47:29 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_BASE:         C:\Users\javed\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1
May 04, 2016 1:47:29 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_HOME:         C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.57
May 04, 2016 1:47:29 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\Users\javed\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1
May 04, 2016 1:47:29 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.57
May 04, 2016 1:47:29 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=C:\Users\javed\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\wtpwebapps
May 04, 2016 1:47:29 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.57\endorsed
May 04, 2016 1:47:29 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252
May 04, 2016 1:47:29 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_20\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jdk1.8.0_20/jre/bin/client;C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jdk1.8.0_20/jre/bin;C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jdk1.8.0_20/jre/lib/i386;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_20\bin;C:\Users\javed\Desktop;;.
May 04, 2016 1:47:33 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
May 04, 2016 1:47:33 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
May 04, 2016 1:47:33 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 11757 ms
May 04, 2016 1:47:33 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
May 04, 2016 1:47:33 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.57
May 04, 2016 1:47:35 PM org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGenerator createSecureRandom
INFO: Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [601] milliseconds.
May 04, 2016 1:47:39 PM com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider info
INFO: Parsing configuration file [struts-default.xml]
May 04, 2016 1:47:39 PM com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider info
INFO: Unable to locate configuration files of the name struts-plugin.xml, skipping
May 04, 2016 1:47:39 PM com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider info
INFO: Parsing configuration file [struts-plugin.xml]
May 04, 2016 1:47:39 PM com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider info
INFO: Parsing configuration file [struts.xml]
May 04, 2016 1:47:39 PM org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory)
May 04, 2016 1:47:39 PM org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.factory.ActionFactory)
May 04, 2016 1:47:39 PM org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.factory.ResultFactory)
May 04, 2016 1:47:39 PM org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.factory.ConverterFactory)
May 04, 2016 1:47:39 PM org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.factory.InterceptorFactory)
May 04, 2016 1:47:39 PM org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.factory.ValidatorFactory)
May 04, 2016 1:47:39 PM org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.factory.UnknownHandlerFactory)
May 04, 2016 1:47:39 PM org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.FileManagerFactory)
May 04, 2016 1:47:39 PM org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.XWorkConverter)
May 04, 2016 1:47:39 PM org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.CollectionConverter)
May 04, 2016 1:47:39 PM org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.ArrayConverter)
May 04, 2016 1:47:39 PM org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.DateConverter)
May 04, 2016 1:47:39 PM org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.NumberConverter)
May 04, 2016 1:47:39 PM org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.StringConverter)
May 04, 2016 1:47:39 PM org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.ConversionPropertiesProcessor)
May 04, 2016 1:47:39 PM org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.ConversionFileProcessor)
May 04, 2016 1:47:39 PM org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.ConversionAnnotationProcessor)
May 04, 2016 1:47:39 PM org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.TypeConverterCreator)
May 04, 2016 1:47:39 PM org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.TypeConverterHolder)
May 04, 2016 1:47:39 PM org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.TextProvider)
May 04, 2016 1:47:39 PM org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.LocaleProvider)
May 04, 2016 1:47:39 PM org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionProxyFactory)
May 04, 2016 1:47:39 PM org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.ObjectTypeDeterminer)
May 04, 2016 1:47:39 PM org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.mapper.ActionMapper)
May 04, 2016 1:47:39 PM org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (jakarta) for (org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.multipart.MultiPartRequest)
May 04, 2016 1:47:39 PM org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (org.apache.struts2.views.freemarker.FreemarkerManager)
May 04, 2016 1:47:39 PM org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (org.apache.struts2.components.UrlRenderer)
May 04, 2016 1:47:39 PM org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ActionValidatorManager)
May 04, 2016 1:47:39 PM org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.ValueStackFactory)
May 04, 2016 1:47:39 PM org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.reflection.ReflectionProvider)
May 04, 2016 1:47:39 PM org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.reflection.ReflectionContextFactory)
May 04, 2016 1:47:39 PM org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.PatternMatcher)
May 04, 2016 1:47:39 PM org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (org.apache.struts2.util.ContentTypeMatcher)
May 04, 2016 1:47:39 PM org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.StaticContentLoader)
May 04, 2016 1:47:39 PM org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.UnknownHandlerManager)
May 04, 2016 1:47:39 PM org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (org.apache.struts2.views.util.UrlHelper)
May 04, 2016 1:47:39 PM org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.TextParser)
May 04, 2016 1:47:39 PM org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.DispatcherErrorHandler)
May 04, 2016 1:47:39 PM org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.security.ExcludedPatternsChecker)
May 04, 2016 1:47:39 PM org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.security.AcceptedPatternsChecker)
May 04, 2016 1:47:39 PM com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.InterceptorBuilder warn
WARNING: Unable to load config class org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor at interceptor - jar:file:/C:/Users/javed/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/Localization/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-core-2.3.28.jar!/struts-default.xml:198:115 probably due to a missing jar, which might be fine if you never plan to use the debugging interceptor
May 04, 2016 1:47:39 PM com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.InterceptorBuilder error
SEVERE: Actual exception
Caught Exception while registering Interceptor class org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor - interceptor - jar:file:/C:/Users/javed/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/Localization/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-core-2.3.28.jar!/struts-default.xml:198:115
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory.buildInterceptor(ObjectFactory.java:202)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.InterceptorBuilder.constructInterceptorReference(InterceptorBuilder.java:59)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.lookupInterceptorReference(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:1092)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.loadInterceptorStack(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:798)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.loadInterceptorStacks(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:811)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.loadInterceptors(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:834)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.addPackage(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:441)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.loadPackages(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:265)
    at org.apache.struts2.config.StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.loadPackages(StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.java:112)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.reloadContainer(DefaultConfiguration.java:189)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:55)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.getContainer(Dispatcher.java:970)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_PreloadConfiguration(Dispatcher.java:438)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:482)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.InitOperations.initDispatcher(InitOperations.java:74)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.init(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:57)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:279)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:260)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:105)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4830)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5510)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$MethodInjector.inject(ContainerImpl.java:295)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.inject(ContainerImpl.java:485)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$6.call(ContainerImpl.java:523)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$6.call(ContainerImpl.java:522)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.callInContext(ContainerImpl.java:574)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.inject(ContainerImpl.java:521)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory.injectInternalBeans(ObjectFactory.java:127)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory.buildBean(ObjectFactory.java:152)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory.buildBean(ObjectFactory.java:139)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory.buildInterceptor(ObjectFactory.java:180)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerBuilder$4.create(ContainerBuilder.java:132)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.Scope$2$1.create(Scope.java:51)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$ParameterInjector.inject(ContainerImpl.java:462)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.getParameters(ContainerImpl.java:477)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.access$000(ContainerImpl.java:34)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$MethodInjector.inject(ContainerImpl.java:293)
    ... 36 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.inject(ContainerImpl.java:495)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$7.call(ContainerImpl.java:532)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.callInContext(ContainerImpl.java:581)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.inject(ContainerImpl.java:530)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.LocatableFactory.create(LocatableFactory.java:32)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerBuilder$4.create(ContainerBuilder.java:130)
    ... 41 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$MethodInjector.inject(ContainerImpl.java:295)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$ConstructorInjector.construct(ContainerImpl.java:431)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.inject(ContainerImpl.java:492)
    ... 46 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$MethodInjector.inject(ContainerImpl.java:293)
    ... 48 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.struts2.views.freemarker.FreemarkerManager.setContainer(FreemarkerManager.java:222)
    ... 53 more

May 04, 2016 1:47:40 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext filterStart
SEVERE: Exception starting filter struts2
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.LocalizedTextUtil.setDevMode(Z)V
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_PreloadConfiguration(Dispatcher.java:444)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:482)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.InitOperations.initDispatcher(InitOperations.java:74)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.init(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:57)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:279)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:260)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:105)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4830)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5510)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

May 04, 2016 1:47:40 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error filterStart
May 04, 2016 1:47:40 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/Localization] startup failed due to previous errors
May 04, 2016 1:47:40 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
SEVERE: The web application [/Localization] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$10] (value [com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$10@1337873]) and a value of type [java.lang.Object[]] (value [[Ljava.lang.Object;@78064a]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
May 04, 2016 1:47:40 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
SEVERE: The web application [/Localization] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$10] (value [com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$10@79805f]) and a value of type [java.lang.Object[]] (value [[Ljava.lang.Object;@f02062]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
May 04, 2016 1:47:40 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
SEVERE: The web application [/Localization] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@182c2f]) and a value of type [com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl] (value [com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl@b82ff0]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
May 04, 2016 1:47:40 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
May 04, 2016 1:47:40 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
May 04, 2016 1:47:40 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 6784 ms
```

Answer (score 1):

> Where to put property files named "global" as base name and "Action" as Base name using eclipse?

The MyAction.properties file should be in the same package as the MyAction class.
The global property files can be anywhere. E.g. put it in one of your source packages like "my.app.i18n" and define in the struts.properties file the path to that package with the key "struts.custom.i18n.resources".

> How does control flow?

Struts tries to find properties files from classname.properties to global.properties. There order is:

```
1. ActionClass.properties
2. Interface.properties (every interface and sub-interface)
3. BaseClass.properties (all the way to Object.properties)
4. ModelDriven's model (if implements ModelDriven), for the model object repeat from 1
5. package.properties (of the directory where class is located and every parent directory all the way to the root directory)
6. search up the i18n message key hierarchy itself
7. global resource properties
```

(Taken from: https://struts.apache.org/docs/localization.html, also read this for more details)

Comment: thank you Sir, i have global properties file placed outside the action containing file.and I am using index.jsp to retrieve values from properties file.. But at runtime Iam getting error:

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Comment: As @Roman suggests, please edit your answer with a full stack trace. For me it looks like you have some other start up issue.

Comment: In that stacktrace there is at least the DebuggingInterceptor missing, this has nothing to do with the properties-files. Please make sure you have all dependencies from struts in your classpath and the jars are valid. Good starting point is [Struts Examples](https://github.com/apache/struts-examples)